# Does a script injected during the load event block other load event handlers?

Tags: javascript, performance

A hypothetical third-party JS vendor provides this script to include in every page:

```
(function() {
    function loadAsync(){
        // Inject the script.
        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://example.com/3rdPartyStuff.js';

        // Find a reasonable place to inject the script.
        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
    }

    // Attach the script loader to the load event.
    if (window.attachEvent) { 
        window.attachEvent('onload', loadAsync); 
    } else { 
        window.addEventListener('load', loadAsync, false); 
    }
})();
```

Do other load event handlers have to wait for this script to *download and execute* before continuing, or can other JS run until this script is available and ready to execute?

Does the answer to this question vary by browser?

Comment: Well your code as written won't work because the code to add the script to the DOM comes before the variable `script` is initialized. However the answer is that the loaded script won't run until the current thread of execution finishes (the window "load" event).

Comment: Sorry, I mocked this up quickly. Fixed.

Comment: Why will the script not run until after the load event? Is it just By Definition an immutable (atomic? terminology fails me) set of instructions?

Comment: JavaScript within a given context (like a page) is synchronous. The browser may start working on fetching the script content on a separate thread, but it won't run it until the "load" event plays out.

Comment: Okay. But if a non-async script is added to that context, does it not become part of that synchronous execution at the point of injection?

Comment: @mac9416 the injected `<script>` will asynchronously load the resource from the `src` URL and dispatch a `load` event when the resource has been downloaded and executed as javascript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts makes sense. But when does the downloaded resource execute? As soon as it's available? After the window's load event is complete?

Comment: @mac9416 As soon as it's available. In some browsers, a resource loaded from cache may even be invoked synchronously, but that behavior is not to be relied on, as it should be expected to load after the current synchronous context as was said by Pointy.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so, as soon as it's available *after* the load event plays out, whether that's immediately after (cached/downloaded quickly) or some time after (slower download). Correct?

Comment: @mac9416 Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pointy and Patrick explained in the comments, the load event fully plays out before any injected scripts execute. I wrote up a demo which confirms this in Chrome, IE, and Edge (I stopped testing after those).

Test it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhh7szyh/3/

In short, I don't have to worry about the third party script slowing down the load event.

Patrick also described the behavior of scripts added with the `async` attribute:

> The default behavior of dynamically injected scripts is to load asynchronously if async is not set, but setting it to false will cause modern browsers to execute it synchronously.

Test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Tests</title>

        <script>

            (function() {

                function sleep(milliseconds) {
                    var start = new Date().getTime();
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                function loadAsync(url){
                    // Inject the script.
                    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.src = url;

                    // Find a reasonable place to inject the script.
                    var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
                    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
                }

                function attach_to_load(fn) {
                    if (window.attachEvent) { 
                        window.attachEvent('onload', fn); 
                    } else { 
                        window.addEventListener('load', fn, false); 
                    }
                }

                attach_to_load(function() { sleep(5000); console.log('before injected JS'); });

                attach_to_load(function() { loadAsync('https://pastebin.com/raw/g40BS6Tg') });

                attach_to_load(function() { sleep(5000); console.log('after injected JS'); });

            })();

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Tests Happened</h1>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, [looking at this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) it appears that on modern browsers, explicitly calling `.setAttribute('async', false)` on the dynamically injected script should cause it to execute synchronously (before other `load` handlers are invoked), but only on modern browsers. This behavior should not be relied upon if targeting full cross-browser compatibility, though.

Comment: I should also correct my first statement, which is in direct conflict with my cited claim about `async=false`. The default behavior of dynamically injected scripts is to load asynchronously if `async` is not set, but setting it to `false` will cause modern browsers to execute it synchronously. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah yep, was about to clarify that with you. Thanks!